# R blmer() how to adjust residual variance to be not fixed at 1?

Tags: r, mixed-models, lmer

I am dealing with blmer() function in **blme package** in R, my sim data has a sigma.epsilon not equal to 1. However when I used blmer() to estimate, I found that **in all cases the output residual variance is 1**. This is contrary to my initial case hence the result was not good. I am wondering if there's any ways to **adjust the residual settings here**? For example by setting any prior information? Thanks in advance!

My code here:

```
# create sim data
N <- 200
n.each <- rep(5,N)
id <- rep(1:N,n.each)
M <- sum(n.each)
intercept <- rep(1, M)
t <- rnorm(M,0,1)
X <- cbind(intercept, t)
Z <- X
p <- ncol(X)
s <- ncol(Z)
true.beta <- c(1,-1)
epsilon <- rnorm(M,0,0.5)
true.theta.mu <- rep(0,s)
onev <- rep(1, s)
true.theta.cov <- rho*onev%*%t(onev)+(1-rho)*diag(1,s)
theta <- mvrnorm(N,true.theta.mu,true.theta.cov)
Theta <- apply(theta,2,rep,n.each)
Y <- X%*%true.beta + rowSums(Z*Theta) + epsilon

# estimation
library(blme)
fm1 <- blmer(Y ~ 1 + t + (1 + t|id), var.prior = "point", cov.prior = "inverse.wishart(df = 99.5, inverse.scale = diag(100,2))", fixef.prior = "normal(cov = diag(1,2))",REML = F,verbose = T)
```

My results (see variance of residual is 1.0000):

```
> summary(fm1)@REmat
 Groups     Name          Variance  Std.Dev.  Corr      
 "id"       "(Intercept)" "0.88994" "0.94337" ""      ""
 ""         "t"           "0.90242" "0.94996" "0.207" ""
 "Residual" ""            "1.00000" "1.00000" ""      ""
```

Comment: For those not familiar with `blmer()`, what package is it in? Your code is not reproducible without that info.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. It's in blme package, I revised my code here.

Answer (score 3):

Think I've got answers from the author: the problem lies in the choice var.prior = "point".

Whenever I put var.prior = "point" it automatically fix sigma.residual at 1.

If we want a flat prior, i.e. no knowledge of information, we better set it to be NULL.

Thanks for the author Mr. Dorie's kind help :)